# Meteor.js - Session not working in mobile browsers

Tags: session, mobile, meteor

Meteor Session set and get is working fine for me across all desktop browsers, but the same events triggering Sessions are "broken" on the mobile safari browser. Is there a work around for this while still using the Meteor Session variable?

Here is an example of the some code.

```
Template.stream.events({
  'click #circusview': function () {
    var thisValue = document.getElementById("circusview");
    var thisVal = thisValue.getAttribute("title");
    Session.set("selected", thisVal);
    var theSesh = Session.get("selected");
  }
}) 

Template.tweet.tmplView = function () {
  var thisSesh = Session.get('selected');
  return thisSesh;
} 

<template name="tweet">
  <div id="{{tmplView}}" class="tweet" style="background-image: url( '{{backImg}}' )" >
    <img class="profile" src="{{profileImg}}">
    <span class="name">{{screenName}}</span>
    <span class="message"> {{thisMessage}}</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

This code works like a charm on desktop browsers, but not on mobile safari.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly happens on mobile Safari? Is the `click` function triggered? Is Session correctly set? Can you test these?

Try this change:

```
Template.stream.events({
  'mouseup #circusview, touchend #circusview': function(e) {
    Session.set('selected', $(e.target).attr('title'));
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Here is the code the is working. Template.stream.events({
  'mouseup #circusview, touchend #circusview': function(e) {
    var thisValue = document.getElementById("circusview");
    var thisVal = thisValue.getAttribute("title");
    Session.set("selected", thisVal);
  },

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Hubert -

Here is the code that ended up working on desktop and mobile.

```
Template.stream.events({
  'mouseup #circusview, touchend #circusview': function(e) {
   var thisValue = document.getElementById("circusview");
   var thisVal = thisValue.getAttribute("title");
   Session.set("selected", thisVal);
  }
})
```